# Arranging the following elements in the increasing order of their oxidising power

Tags: electrochemistry, reduction-potential

I was given the following equations and asked to arrange them in increasing order of their oxidizing power:

- $\ce{Co^{+3} + e- -> Co^{+2}}$ with an electrode potential of $+1.81\, \mathrm{V}$
- $\ce{Pb^{+4} + 2e^{-} -> Pb^{+2}}$, with an electrode potential of $1.67\, \mathrm{V}$
- $\ce{Ce^{+4} + e^{-} -> Ce^{+3}}$ ,
  with an electrode potential of $1.61\, \mathrm{V}$
- $\ce{Bi^{3+} + 3e^{-} ->Bi}$. with an electrode potential of  $0.20\, \mathrm{V}$

as electrode potential is the same as reducing potential,  the greater a substance's reduction potential, the lesser its oxidsing power.

So I Got: $$ \ce{Bi^{+3} > Ce^{+4} > Pb^{+4} > Co^{+3}}$$
however, my book says that this is wrong. Why is this wrong?

Comment: What does your book say? Your order is correct. Co(III) is a powerful oxidizer and bismuth is almost nil.

Comment: my bad, I wrote it the other way round, why is that wrong? Why is this order correct?

Comment: Now that you have edited the order, then you have to re-visit the concept of electrode potentials and its relation to oxidizing power. It will be a 30 minute lecture, I were to explain it. And also learn the use of the symbols < and > properly. In short, re-visit the textbook explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A higher reduction potential correlates to higher oxidation power. Think about a redox reaction: one of the reagents gets reduced (gains electrons), and the other gets oxidized (loses electrons). The more one reagent favours reduction (higher electrode potential), the more strongly that reagent can act as an oxidizing agent on another reagent.